# Titanium (Android) - Invite Facebook-Friends -> error

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, titanium

i have an problem with my Appcelerator Titanium. I want to use the Facebook API to send Invites to a User's friends, but i always get the same error.

Here is my code, i have no special Facebook permissions set (maybe i have to?):

```
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    Ti.App.fb.dialog('apprequests', {message: 'my custom message'}, function(data) { 
      alert(data);
    });
}
```

And this is the error i after sending the request via the Facebook Dialog:

> {cancelled=true, success=false, code=-1}

I've googled this error, then i've found this:
[Appcelerator Error Ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/MOD-1900)

So i think, maybe thats the problem, but this ticket ist from Sept '13. It's still open, but i thought maybe it's solved, after over a year. Does anyone have an fix for my problem ? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have the needed permissions. I guess you need these at least:

```
fb.permissions = ['publish_stream'];
fb.authorize();
```

I think you use the Titanium Facebook module(?). You should definitely check the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Modules.Facebook) since it is very detailed.